# 2021 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1#questionnaire).**

---

Islam Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election [next week, 2021-06-28](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2021-06-28 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: "next week, 2021-07-09" seems kinda ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, guess there's a bug in the automatic generation of this post — fixed in this post in the meantime, but thanks for noticing so we can fix that bug, @goldPseudo ;)

Answer (score 5):

We attract a lot of low-quality questions from users with little to no expertise in Islamic topics, which can often drown out questions on more advanced topics. The community has a wide array of privilege-based tools (e.g. voting, editing) to curate the site and maintain a standard of quality. How important do you feel the moderator's role is in this process?

Comment: I definitely agree. It's really frustrating to see so many easily searchable answers to other people's questions posted on this site.

Answer (score 2):

[Islam Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=islam.stackexchange.com) and [Islam Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com) are both valuable tools for gauging the needs and priorities of the community, but the community has not been particularly inclined to take advantage of them. As a moderator, how crucial would you consider this sort of community engagement and what, if anything, do you feel should be done to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

As a pluralistic site, Islam.SE is meant to be both welcoming and useful for questions on all denominations of Islam. How well do you believe it has accomplished this so far and what do you feel could be done to improve the experience of under-represented and less mainstream users?

Answer (score 2):

As a Moderator on stackexchange you are supposed to work together with other moderators and the community.
How would you handle a situation in which another moderator closed/deleted a question which you think he/she shouldn't have?

Answer (score 2):

As this site is pluralistic, sooner or later you - as one of the moderators- or the community will close a question. However the reaction on this closure might be a meta post complaining about your "anti pluralistic" behavior (direct reference to moderator "X").

How would you react? Or
Will you react on such a post?
If yes under what circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

From time to time we have a huge activity of people who certainly have good intentions, but want to preach the "truth".
What do you think is the best way to handle with such people and situations?

Answer (score 1):

As a moderator, your actions and behaviour will reflect not only the Islam.SE community, but the Stack Exchange network as a whole: This will likely involve endorsing and enforcing policies that you may disagree with personally. How do you feel about that? Does it matter if the point of contention stems from your religious beliefs rather than just a personal conviction?

Answer (score 1):

Under which condition would you delete or hide

- a question?
- an answer?
- a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Many low quality question posts come either from Muslims with a bad basis in their religion or from non-Muslims who are simply curious about something.

Would you make a difference between low-quality questions on a specific basis? For example the religious background?

Answer (score 0):

There are many people who ask a question here and in fact look for a fatwa for their specific case. Or in other words want you to give them clear guidance or make decision for them.

You may leave them an answer. But they will keep asking you in comments something like "are you really meaning to say if I do such and such it is halal/haram"...

Do you have an idea how to deal with that? Should a moderator react in such a case assuming it was not him whom answered the question?